# How do we want to handle questions about unstable/incomplete contributed modules for D8?

Tags: discussion

Have a look at [this recent comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/226964/timeline#comment_277349), which include this:

> ... debugging sites in-situ can't be supported by Q+A, because as soon as you fix the issue the question ceases to make sense.

I do agree with that ... **but**, what about all those D8 questions about unstable/incomplete contributed modules (rules, commerce, etc)? Shouldn't those be considered like that also? I.e: ***`As soon as the D8 releases for those modules become more mature, all those questions cease to make sense also ...`***.

Here are just a few samples, related to some well known modules:

- [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules):

  - [Send email notification with Rules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/201079/39516)
  - [How do I use the Rules module to unpublish content when End Date is hit?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/211151/39516)
  - https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/226891/39516
  - [How do I redirect anonymous users to the login?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/201545/39516)
- [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce):

  - [How to make a user role expire after 1 year?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/218197/39516)
  - https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/226966/39516
  - [8 - Product reference add to cart form shows only add to cart button](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/197427/39516)
  - [Receiving an error when uninstall](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/204393/39516)

So, how do we want to handle this moving forward? Are we allowed to flag (or vote to close) such questions as of topic (or anything similar to that)?

Comment: The comment makes sense for the question, since it essentially require to debug a site, but doing so will possibly help just the OP. For the modules, that is quite different, since there are modules that stay without a stable release for a long period of time. Also, the question, in that case, could help other users using the same module. That is different from having a different site running the same combination of third-party and custom modules another site is using.

Comment: In short, it could be there are questions about modules that are important only when using a specific version, but I would not be too fast in closing them.